# Using Config Parameter in Twig Extension

Tags: symfony, twig

I am creating Twig extensions so I can create custom filters and functions. I need to access a globally configured parameter in the 'parameters.ini' file.

How would I go about that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can pass them via dependency injection. Either pass the parameters via the constructor or use setter methods. This example uses xml for service definitions:

```php
public class MyExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    protected $param;

    public function __construct($param)
    {
        $this->param = $param;
    }
}
```

---

```xml
<!-- in services.xml -->
<service id="my_bundle.twig.extension.name" class="Acme\Bundle\DemoBundle\Twig\Extension\MyExtension">
    <argument>%my_parameter%</argument>
    <tag name="twig.extension" />
</service>
```

Notice how the parameter is confined in percentage symbols. You can read more about dependency injection from the [official book](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#service-parameters).

Comment: Not sure if I follow, @gilden. The Twig extension is defined in my services.yml. I thought of setting an argument that should pick up values from the parameters.ini.

`services:

    myap.twig.myapp_extension:
        class: MyApp\MainBundle\Twig\MyappExtension
        arguments:
            - { encrypt_salt: %encrypt_salt%, foo: 'some value' }
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }`

Provided that this works, is there some way to pick up the value of 'encrypt_salt' in the extension class?

Comment: Your previous comment was missing some code. :-)  So, I'm definitely on the right track. Question now is how I pick up the argument value in the extension class?

Comment: @jbsound Sorry for that, had some formatting issues. You can enclose the parameter name in `%` symbols in yml as well. All the arguments are passed to the constructor of the class. Just assign the value to a property and use it in your other methods.

Comment: Yeah, just tested it and the passing through the constructor is the way to go. Thanks for the help! I wonder if the same would work with getter/setter methods. Anyways, this will work!

Comment: How would the code look like for the setter method? What setter name would Symfony expect to be there?

Comment: @jbsound The official book explains quite well: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#optional-dependencies-setter-injection

Answer (score 2):

This is not a good practice to use container in Twig extensions but you can pass the service_container as argument when declaring your twig extension in services.xml

```
 <service id="example.twig.my_extension" class="Example\CoreBundle\Twig\MyExtension">
            <argument type="service" id="service_container" />
            <tag name="twig.extension" />
        </service>
```

add the ContainerInterface argument in the __construct() function declaration :

```
<?php
namespace Example\CoreBundle\Twig;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class MyExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{    
    /**
     * @var ContainerInterface
     */
    private $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }
    ...
```

(Do not forget to use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface)

Call your config parameters in your functions like this:

```
$this->container->getParameter('key');
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible in Twig views, but in the controller you can do:

```
$this->container->getParameter('name_of_ini_value');
```

Comment: Definitely in the controller. Problem is that the container is not available in a Twig extension.

Comment: Nice to hear that. So my skills stops there.